# How could I compute my "candidate score"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderators, badges, election

I have noticed that, during elections for moderators, the candidates are awarded a "candidate score", computed from their activity on MO.

> Is its algorithm public, so that I be able to compute it for myself, to know where I stand?

In particular, I have noticed that it depends on the number of badges accumulated in three badge classes (moderating, editing, participation), and I have no idea which of the available badges on MO belong to which class. Furthermore, it seems that the total number of badges in these classes is 8 + 6 + 6 = 20, while the total number of badges available to a MO user is significantly larger that this. Therefore,

> what are the badges in these three classes?

Finally,

> do reputation points play any role in this algorithm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The criteria are described exactly in [What are the details on the "candidate score" which shows during an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election). Moreover, [What would my Election Candidate score be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253781/what-would-my-election-candidate-score-be) includes a link to a SEDE query that lets one compute their candidate score.

Comment: I will just add that, when using SEDE queries, one should keep in mind switching the site to MathOverflow. And you also need the userid, but that can be found easily from the user's profile: [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771) Some posts and queries related to candidate score [were also mentioned in the election chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=score&room=122425).

Comment: I guess it tickles my pride, but I was not unhappy with my score.